# How to Change Date Format in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I've tried pulling outlook emails in an excel table via power automate. All the details are getting pulled in respective columns; however date & time is getting pulled in different format i.e. 27-07-2022T12:40:11+00:00. May I know how can I get it in certain format i.e. dd-mmm-yyyy at hh:mm:ss IST? Below is the power automate process flow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your date is UTC, you can use the `convertFromUtc` function to do the conversion. Use 'India Standard Time' for IST as 2nd parameter and as 3rd parameter add the needed format.

```
convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'India Standard Time','dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

In case your date is not UTC. use the `convertTimeZone` function.

Alternatively there is also a convert time zone action.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.